# Finding $\lim \limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{(z-i)^2}$ rigorously

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I want to find the limit of the following:
$$\lim \limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{(z-i)^2}$$

And to me, I can see that the denominator is clearly $0$, and since we are in the extended complex plane, I feel I can now immediately say that:

$$\lim \limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{(z-i)^2}=\infty$$
But this doesn't feel very rigorous or justified. How do I do it in a justified way?

Comment: You would have to assume that $ \infty $ is the object that, when adjoined to $ \mathbb{C} $, makes it the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Yes there is no limit in $\mathbb{C}$. The function has a "pole" (of order 2) at $z=i$, which means that there is no limit and also quite far reaching consequences for line integrals close to it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the extended complex plane as the Riemann sphere, where $ \infty $ is viewed as the north pole of the sphere. To make your argument rigorous, you can use the stereographic projection to see that the limit of the expression is the north pole.

Alternatively, viewing the extended complex plane as a **one-point compactification** of the complex plane, you simply have to ensure that for any compact subset $ K $ of $ \mathbb{C} $, there exists a punctured neighborhood $ U $ of $ i $ such that $ \dfrac{1}{(z - i)^{2}} \notin K $ for all $ z \in U $.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$z = i+w$.
The fraction is then
$\frac1{w^2}$.
For any real $v > 0$,
if
$|w| < 1/\sqrt{v}$,
then
$|\frac1{w^2}|
> v$.

So the limit *is* $\infty$,
since for any $v > 0$
we can find a neighborhood
of $i$
where the function is
always greater than
$v$.

Comment: This coupled with the fact that there are many values in $\mathbb{C}$ for every absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this theorem is useful.

$\displaystyle \lim_{z\to z_{0}}f(z)=\infty$ iff $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to z_{0}}\frac{1}{f(z)}=0$. ($\lim_{z\to w}f(z)=\infty$ if given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\displaystyle \delta>0$ such that $|z-w|<\delta\implies |f(z)|>\epsilon$).

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ for a real function, a requirement for the limit to exist, is that the right-hand limit and the left-hand limit are equal; $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)$ then we say that the limit exists and $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$.

In the complex plan, however, there are not just two but an infinite number of directions to go from $z$ to $z_0$, though only two linearly independent ones (along the real and imaginary axises, respectively). In order for you to rigorously show that the limit $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)$ exists, you have to show that it is independent of the direction of approach.

But as mentioned earlier, the limit does *not* exist i $\mathbb{C}$, but in $\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\check{\infty}\}$, you *can* however show that indeed the limit does exist and is equal to $\check{\infty}$ by using the method mentioned above.